# dual Kali linux instances windows wsl2

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, kali-linux, parrot-os

I am trying to run kali and parrotos side by side on windows wsl. Parrot os can just be installed over kali, so really I just need to figure out how to create two kali machines. I found some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51584765/how-do-you-install-multiple-separate-instances-of-ubuntu-in-wsl), but I am not sure what method is right for me. Is there a way to launch to grub menu to select which installation I want to use? Ideally, I would like to launch the same kali app from windows store and select which kali distro to use.

Comment: I am using Kali here. Some who have tried Kali in WSL have had to revert to a VM.  Kali is not really meant for WSL use and WSL is not a really good VM App.  Somewhere i have a Parrot machine and same thing for Parrot

Comment: Virtual machines are so sluggish in my experience. The kali desktop is interesting with it's seamless mode

Comment: I have Kali in a VMware VM on an SSD and it is quite fast

Comment: @Sean that of course depends on the specs of machine you are running the VM on. If you plan to run 3 systems simultaneously (windows as hypervisor, kali, parrot), you of course need enough resources to do so. Having the VMs virtual disk on a separate physical disk would definitely help.

Comment: is there a way to access folders on the C: drive from windows?

Comment: Yes, I do this routinely.   Map the Windows Drive in Kali.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to run kali and parrotos side by side on windows wsl.

This is best done running Kali in a true Virtual machine. I am doing just that here.

> is there a way to access folders on the C: drive from windows?

Yes. Two ways:

(1) From Kali:    smb://192.168.x.y/sharedfolder  where 192.168.x.y is the IP address of the Windows host. I have that mapping in place here.

(2) From Windows:

Install Samba in Kali and map a Kali folder from Windows. This works but is more complicated.

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-samba#2-installing-samba